# Reactive Form: Multiple layers of a form in one FormGroupName / FormControlname

Tags: angular

Is it possible to pass in a reactive form multiple layers of a form in one formGroupName / formControlName Directive?

For example:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
  names = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl('')
  })
});
```

And in an Input Field i want to directly access the path name.firstName without an outer formGoupName at a div.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use some in the way

```
<!--careful, it not work-->
<input [formControl]="profileForm.get('names.firstName')"/>
```

The problem is that [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) return an abstractControl so you need use a getter

```
//in .ts
get firstNameControl()
{
    return profileForm.get('names.firstName') as FormControl
}

    <!--using the getter before-->
    <input [formControl]="firstNameControl"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `formControlName` directive:

```
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    <div formGroupName="names">
       <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
       <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
    </div>
  </form>
```